# OpenGL: Why far and near are negative in orthogonal projection?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, orthographic

Why are the near and far coordinates are interpreted as negative in orthographic projection? Is it just customary or there is really any benefit of this?

Comment: Perhaps it's some extremely lazy way to spell *negative*?

Comment: Thanks Krom for having a look. I see the arguments of glArtho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far) which forms a viewing box with set of coordinates {(left, bottom, -near), (right, bottom, -near), (left, top, -near), (right, top, -near), (left, bottom, -far), (right, bottom, -far), (left, top, -far), (right, top, -far)}........I was curious if interpretation of near and far as negative has some benefit...Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really think there's any reason. Using orthographic projection you can set your near/far planes to be anything, it just defines what z values you want to be displayed. I can't think of any particular benefit to this.

Answer (score 11):

The near and far clipping planes can be anything you want and I think the confusion here is because in OpenGL "forward" or into the screen is -Z.  So if I want to see things from the origin to 100 units in front of me, the near will be 0 and the far is -100.  But I could also have said I want to see things 30 units behind the origin to 50 units in front in which case near would be 30 and far would be -50.

An added confusion to all this is that glOrtho takes near and far clipping planes but reverses the sign on them to "help" you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It isn't arbitrary at all: the convention in most graphics systems, as you point out, is that the camera aims in the -z direction.

Answer (score 4):

> Why are the near and far coordinates are interpreted as negative in orthographic projection?

Who says that they are? There's no rule that the near/far values *must* be negative in orthographic projections. Your question assumes facts not in evidence.